# Extraction from multiple html files (same kind of data) and storing the results in a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, glob

I want to extract specific data from multiple html files (having the same arrangement) and store it in a single dataframe. The script I wrote (see below) extracts information only from the last file in the folder.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os.path
counter = 0


dir_path = r"/home"    


for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.html")):
    with open(file_name) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)
        counter = counter+1

        text = []
        vessel_name = []
        port = []
        voy_no = []

        for p_tag in soup.find_all('p', {'class' : 'MsoNormal'}):
            text.append(p_tag.text)

        text1 = [el.replace('\xa0',' ') for el in text]

        a = text1[2].split(":")[1]
        vessel_name.append((list(a.split())))

        b = text1[4].split(":")[1]
        voy_no.append((b.split()))

        c = text1[5].split(":")[1]
        port.append((c.split()))

        dict_for_df = {'Vessel_Name':vessel_name, 'Voy_No':voy_no, 'Port':port}

    final_df = pd.DataFrame.append(dict_for_df)
```

Comment: and what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, create an emtpy dataframe at the beginning

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

and add to that later

```
final_df = final_df.append(dict_for_df)
```

The full code is

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import glob
import os.path
counter = 0

final_df = pd.DataFrame()

dir_path = r"/home"    

for file_name in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, "*.html")):
    with open(file_name) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)
        counter = counter+1

        text = []
        vessel_name = []
        port = []
        voy_no = []

        for p_tag in soup.find_all('p', {'class' : 'MsoNormal'}):
            text.append(p_tag.text)

        text1 = [el.replace('\xa0',' ') for el in text]

        a = text1[2].split(":")[1]
        vessel_name.append((list(a.split())))

        b = text1[4].split(":")[1]
        voy_no.append((b.split()))

        c = text1[5].split(":")[1]
        port.append((c.split()))

        dict_for_df = {'Vessel_Name':vessel_name, 'Voy_No':voy_no, 'Port':port}

        final_df = final_df.append(dict_for_df)
```

Note that this is not the best way to do it. If your data fits in memory, better collect all data in a list of directories and create the dataframe at the end. For a small dataset of a 1000 lines or less this should be good enough.